# C# 9 relational pattern in switch expression in ASP.NET Core Razor CSHTML

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor

A switch expression something like:

```
string c = b.Date.CompareTo(now.Date) switch { < 0 => "before", > 0 => "after", _ => "today" };
```

is valid C# 9.0, but it seems to confuse Razor:

```
@{
    string c = b.Date.CompareTo(now.Date) switch { < 0 => "before", > 0 => "after", _ => "today" };
}
```

I get an error at the `<` (less than) symbol

> The element "" was not closed' RZ1025

It's not the less than itself -

```
@{
    if (1 < 2) {...}
}
```

is fine.

Obviously, I could replace the switch with an if/elseif/else set, but I'd like to use the more compact version if I can.

Comment: Don't put embed complex code in Razor in the first place. It makes the code a *lot* harder to read and maintain. Same for collapsing complex pattern matching expressions in a single line. ASP.NET Core 5 didn't support all C# 9 features in Razor but even 6 will have problems sometimes. Separating display and logic is simply cleaner. Try creating a small function in the `@code` section

Comment: The Razor compiler doesn't compile directly to IL. The Razor code is converted to C# and *that* is what is actually compiled. The Razor compiler doesn't always support the latest C# features. That happened both in ASP.NET Core 3.1 and ASP.NET Core 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can workaround by using parenthesis (or just by moving this logic into some function outside the Razor markup, for example extension one or possibly encapsulating it in a tag helper):

```cs
@{
    string c = DateTime.Now.CompareTo(DateTime.Now.Date) switch 
    {
        (< 0) => "before", 
        (> 0) => "after", 
        _ => "today" 
    };
}
```

**UPD**

It seems that this is a known [Razor compiler bug](https://github.com/dotnet/razor-compiler/issues/241).

Comment: One could make a strong argument that such code should be a separate function, not embedded in the Razor markup. No matter what the actual stack is (MVC, Razor Pages, Blazor)